# click event of jquery is not working with me

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a page mainform.php where I want that when I press the button so the data gets loads up here in a table or any element of my choice. But when I press the button so it does not bring the data. I've tried to show it first in console but not even displayed there. Here is my mainform.php code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btnClear").on("click", function(){
            function loadData(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "show-cart.php",
                    type: "POST", 
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(data){                     
                        /*$.each(data, function(key, value){
                              $("#showme").append(value.item_name);  
                        });*/
                        console.log(data);
                    }        
                }); 
            }
            });        
        })
```

And here is my show-cart.php code where the mySql code is executed:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chargha") or die ("Your Connection Failed");

$sql = "SELECT items.item_id, items.item_name, items.item_unit_price, cart.order_qty, cart.order_price, cart.order_of, cart.order_instructions, cart.token_id from cart LEFT JOIN items ON cart.item_id = items.item_id";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$output = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC); //It transform the array into associative one. mysqli_asssoc, num, both

echo json_encode($output); ?>
```

Question:
**1.** What is wrong happening with this click event code, I've executed the show-cart.php page code separately and its all working.
**2.** Do I need to type the datatype: "JSON" every time whenever I work with AJAX or jQuery?
Thank you very much.

[image]
For further clarification of the problem, I'm adding further details. The above image is the screenshot of my mozilla firefox browser's Debugger Tab where on Right side there is an Error and details. And in the center there is jquery.js file in red color.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in the code in question, `loadData` function is defined in click event but not invoked in the event.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnClear").on("click", function () {
        function loadData() {
            // Your code here
        }
        // Call method
        loadData();
    });
});
```

Secondly, you may prefer to write the click event code directly without defining `loadData` method

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnClear").on("click", function () {
        // Your code here, no need to define any internal method
        $.ajax({
            // ...
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I've put my function out of the click event and just made a call to the function from my click event, as you mentioned. But yet no data received. Please guide.

Comment: Can you check in the network tab of dev tools, is the ajax call hitting the correct URL?

Comment: I don't know how to check. But in my Firefox, F12 brought me Inspect Element and there I have multiple columns i.e. Status, Method, Domain, File, Initiator. I don't see show-cart.php page over here?
Is it the right place to check, where you are asking me for?

Comment: Yeah, that is the right place. Keep the tab open, then perform the click action to check.

Comment: Yeah. There is a red mark (circle with diagonal line inside) and under initiator column its written jquery.js:2(xhr) where xhr is in red color and under Transferred column there is red color NS-Binding-Aborted

Comment: The tab is open and after clicking the button there is a first row in the tab and that is red.
Does it mean that my request is not hitting the required URL?

Comment: Yes. It is getting aborted beforehand. Possibilities. Try with GET call instead of POST since there is no data being posting. Also, add error callback for ajax call to check for errors.

Comment: I've tried, $.post, $.get, $.getJSON, $.ajax, none of them is bringing me result that I want..

Comment: The code is working fine when I checked. Are you dealing with this button in HTML form? Provide some HTML content to check.

Comment: One thing I'm not sure about. In my code (as I'm new to web development) there is dataype = "JSON"?
Please explain that under what condition we use it?
Because when I remove this line of code, so some of my problem solved?

Comment: In my code first block, under the loadData function there is a commented code of my dive #showme. When I enable it or when I place any other html element in this code and click the button so I get this error in Debugger tab that ((Paused on Exception: TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "length" in "[{\"item_id\":\"4\",..."))
Note: I want to mention that I've already separate the click event code and the loadData function. Why I'm having this debugger error?

Comment: Can you check if adding `type="button"` to `btnClear` element resolves the error?

Comment: Yes, I've already solved 2 issues: I removed the datatype="JSON" and changed replaced the 'type="submit"' to 'type="button"'. BUT the error is there in the Debugger.